# magento 1.7.0.2 404 error when switching store view code

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2 and have 3 store views. When I'm in a category and switch to other store views (language) I get a 404 error. For example:

I'm here: www.example.com/en/cars.html  and whant to switch to spanish. It would change to:

www.example.com/es/coches.html but it moves to www.example.com/coches.html (without the store view code) and that gives a 404 error.

This only happens when the url is translated. If not, it works.

I searched for days and didn't find a solution.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Did you change the base url of the es storeview to www.example.com/es/ ?

Comment: Sounds like you may have to add rewrites via the Magento admin for the categories you mentioned. They should be automatically added but it sounds like they haven't been.